# How to get only access token from data

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt, token, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have setting up a login system and I need only the access token, when i console.log my data, i get the Refresh and Token code all at once. I want just the access token even without the quotation mark please.

this is my Login Screen:

```
const handleSubmit = async ({ username, password }) => {
    const result = await authApi.login(username, password);
    if (!result.ok) return setLoginFailed(true);
    setLoginFailed(false);
    console.log(result.data);
```

Ordinarily i get something like this :
"refresh": "eyJ0eX....refreshtoken", access": "eyJ0eX...accesstoken...i4ec"

But what i need is just      -     eyJ0eX...accesstoken...i4ec (i.e. just the access token without the quotation marks) please

Comment: This is what i get `"refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTAwNjMwNiwianRpIjoiMDhhZjQ2YzJjZWU5NDg1NDg0ZWVhNDNlODNlOGRlMmEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.LwyaNXex2mReoWfC9eSwYfztFfuebsi1QaX0mYes58c",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjA3Nzk3MDA2LCJqdGkiOiJmODNlMTE2NjM1ZmQ0NmU3Yjk2MGE4MmRiN2Q3NTYzNCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.WlSdNfx5HtpNGiXbcxaoo6xr0SLiJjT1JPODwWd1UEc"`

Comment: And all i want is just the access code ....eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjA3Nzk3MDA2LCJqdGkiOiJmODNlMTE2NjM1ZmQ0NmU3Yjk2MGE4MmRiN2Q3NTYzNCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.WlSdNfx5HtpNGiXbcxaoo6xr0SLiJjT1JPODwWd1UEc

Comment: WOW! i cant believe thats where i got it wrong. Thanks. Im very grateful

Comment: Typo-based questions aren't a good suite for the site. I have voted to close this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo. Use this instead:

```js
console.log(result.data.access);
```

Comment: While it is commendable to help the OP with some directions by commenting, it is recommended to not answer questions worthy of being closed. This question's primary problem is caused by a typo, and is due to that, not suitable for our QA format.

Comment: View https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (I have sent the ask link so that you may see what sort of questions are not welcomed here and take your decision in answering them accordingly).